# скрыть элемент по клику вне div

Tags: jquery

Доброго дня, очень нужна помощь, есть скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#contact').click(function () {
    $( ".right-content" ).animate({ opacity: "toggle"}, 200, "linear", function() { });
});
});
```

Как сделать так чтобы при клике вне блока .right-content и кнопки с #contact, блок .right-content сворачивался? Может кто уже сталкивался с такой задачей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest(".right-content, #contact").length) return; // Если клик в .right-content или #contact выходим из функции
    $('.right-content').slideUp(); // Если не вышли - сворачиваем див
});
```

Пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/jhkLwub4/

Comment: Благодарю все в точку!!!

Answer (score 1):

Через `.one` подписаться на клик по `$(document)`, в обработчике проверить, что этот клик не внутри того div'а. Затем скрыть.